# How do you pass R.Drawable as a parameter in a custom ImageView

Tags: android, class, parameter-passing, drawable

I have a super simple class, it extends ImageView. I would like to add (in it's constructor) a parameter for an `R.Drawable`. ideally, I can then instantiate the custom `Char` class, and I would have a nice little `ImageView` with a background. I understand that this is fundamentally possible by just making an imageview and that I'm not customizing anything. This is more for learning though. How to I pass R.Drawable as a parameter? The code below states I can't assign a drawable to an int.

**DOUBLE UPDATE:**
*For a brief moment I saw an answer that said to just use `int` as a parameter. I thought of this, but that doesn't seem to be graceful at all. I figure Android probably has a more graceful way of approaching this. I tried looking through source doc but got lost in the maze. Apparently that IS the right answer though.*

```
*imports*


public class Char extends ImageView {

    Char (Context context, R.drawable drawable){
        super(context);
        setBackgroundResource(drawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Char extends ImageView {

    /**
     * Constructor for <code>Char</code>
     * 
     * @param context The {@link Context} to use
     * @param resId The resource identifier of the {@link Drawable}
     */
    public Char(Context context, int resId) {
        super(context);
        setImageResource(resId);
    }

}
```

To use it call: `new Char(your_context, R.drawable.your_drawable))`

Comment: I Googled around. Apparently this really is the way to go. I just thought it was weird. Well all's well that ends well.

Comment: Hmmm, well I'm not exactly sure what you find weird about it. But if you'd like a more detailed explanation I'd be happy to help.

Comment: It seems to leave room for error. an int can be, well an int. I mean, any number. The R.id is fairly specific. I figure there'd be a specific object that keeps the passed parameter on the straight and narrow. I mean, I could pass "2" and it would throw all sorts of errors. I just find it weird that there's not an encompassing class for R.Drawable. Then again, making the drawable and passing the drawable seems to be more along the lines of how I thought it would be. Just threw me for a loop is all.

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. Passing in `2` would throw a `ResourceNotFoundException` that Android actually catches, so nothing would display in that case. But you use `R.drawable...` because that's also an `int` that's automatically generated by Android. If you look in your `gen` folder under `R.java` you'll see all of your resources are given a `static final int`, that's essentially their ID.

Comment: in my case stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 2):

The answer you saw of passing an int is the correct one. Either that or you can create the drawable, pass it in and use that

```
public class Char extends ImageView {

    Char (Context context, Drawable drawable) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable.xxx` is an int, so just pass an int parameter to your function.